# check string to be 1, 0 else print string

Tags: python, c, arduino, pyserial

I have an arduino connected to my computer (COM9) and I have 3 python scripts. The first sends a "1" over serial.
The second sends a "0" over serial.
The third sends a word that you give it.

```
ser.write("1")
```

Then on my arduino I have some code. 
If the python script 1 is launched it would turn on a led. If the 2 second script is launched it would turn off a led. If python script 3 is launched it would print the word to an lcd.

All hardware is configured correctly.
The problem is that when I run script 1 not only the led would turn on but there will also be a 1 on the lcd. The other 2 scripts work as expected.

This is a part of the code on my arduino.

```
 if (Serial.available())
  {
     wordoftheday = Serial.readString();
     if (wordoftheday == "1"){email = true;}
     if (wordoftheday == "0"){email = false;}
     else { 
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.print(wordoftheday);
      }
  }

  if (email == true){digitalWrite(9, HIGH);}
  if (email == false){digitalWrite(9, LOW);}
```

Comment: Do you want `else if (wordoftheday == "0")`?

Comment: @TristanT it is unclear what you want the LED to do when the third textual message type is received.

Comment: @Weather when the third textual message type is received. the led needs to do nothing. If it is on it needs to stay on. If it is off it needs to stay off

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't compare strings using `==`

```
if (wordoftheday == "1"){email = true;}
```

should be

```
if (strcmp(wordoftheday, "1") == 0){email = true;}
```

And (as pointed out by @chux), it seems that you forget an `else`:

```
 if (strcmp(wordoftheday, "1") == 0)
     email = true;
 else
 if (strcmp(wordoftheday, "0") == 0)
     email = false;
 else { 
     lcd.clear();
     lcd.print(wordoftheday);
 }
```

Comment: There is another logic flaw: as @chux mentioned, there is a missing `else`.

Comment: This was very helpfull. But it does raise an error. `cannot convert 'String' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int strcmp(const char*, const char*)' `
I know what it says. But why does it say it?

Comment: @TristanT are you writing in Python or in C? Seeing as your program worked, apart from your question *why is there a value on the LCD?* Which is solved by adding the `else`

Comment: Ok, I didn't see the `python` tag,  `wordoftheday` is declared as string? then change to `if (!strcmp(wordoftheday.c_str(), "1"))`

Comment: It worked `if (strcmp(wordoftheday.c_str(), "1") == 0)`

Answer (score 2):

Besides the previous answer about the compare, you are setting up the ifs incorrectly. When the first if is true, you fall into the else of the second if.

```
if (Serial.available())
{
    wordoftheday = Serial.readString();
    if (strcmp(wordoftheday, "1")) {email = true;}
    else if ((strcmp(wordoftheday, "0")){email = false;}
    else { 
        // Enters here only if both of the above are false
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.print(wordoftheday);
    }
}
```